# Change value of a randomly chosen entry of a sparse matrix row

Tags: python, numpy

`vec` is one row of a sparse matrix.

```
vec = sparse.csc_matrix([[0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1]])
```

How can I randomly choose 2 entries with value '1' and change its value to 8?

I have tried

```
a,b,c = sparse.find(vec==1)
idx = numpy.random.choice(vec[a,b],2)
vec[idx] = 8
```

However I am getting dimension error because `vec` is one of the rows of a larger sparse matrix and is something like a nested array.

Comment: try: `idx = 0, np.random.choice(b, 2, False)`

Answer (score 0):

This converts your sparse row to a boolean mask for your operations.

```
ones = np.stack(np.where((vec==1).toarray())).T # [[i,j],[i,j]..]
chosen = np.random.choice(len(ones), 2) # [1,3]
for index in chosen:
    vec[tuple(ones[index])] = 8
```

Since this is by row I think you'll not run into memory problems.